# Not able to launch the app due to Untrusted Enterprise Developer issue

Tags: appium-ios

I am not able to launch the app as I am getting the “Untrusted Enterprise Developer” issue while executing the test case on iOS using appium.

Even if I go to the settings on the iPhone and select to trust the developer those privileges are revoked while starting the next test case and I find myself having to do this again.

Do you have any ideas why we might need to keep trusting this application to run on our iPhone and is there any way to overcome from this?

Comment: Hi, The iOS app should be signed with a proper certificate (developer account) to avoid "Untrusted Enterprise Developer" issue. This issue occurs due to a personal certificate and iPhone prompts this message for every installation of app. These capabilities will help you if app is not required to reinstall every time. ```noReset Don't reset app state before this session. See here for more details true, false
fullReset Perform a complete reset. See here for more details true, false```

Comment: http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/caps/